# Compute the Jordan normal form of a $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

> For $t \in \Bbb R$, consider
>
> $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
>     0 & t \\
>     0 & 0 \\
>     \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Compute the Jordan normal form of $A$. Distinguish between $t=0$ and $t \neq 0$.

What I have done so far. I tried to find the eigenvalues when $t=0$ or any other number and I got $2$ eigenvalues which both are $0$. How do I proceed from here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $t=0$, then $A=0$ the zero matrix which is already in Jordan form.

If $t\neq 0$, then define $P=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{t}& 0 \\ 0& 1\end{pmatrix}$. Note that $P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} t& 0 \\ 0& 1\end{pmatrix}$. Direct calculation reveals $PAP^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 1\\ 0& 0\end{pmatrix}$, which is in Jordan form.

Comment: How did you find the 1/t?

Comment: I want the (1,2) entry of $A$ to become 1. This suggests the choice of $1/t$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

- if $t=0$ then $A$ is already in a Jordan normal form.
- if $t \neq 0$ then by considering the basis $((t,0),(0,1))$ you can show that:
  $$A \sim \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Did you take t=1 in your example?

Comment: No. Try to write for any $t \neq 0$ the matrix in the new base ((t,0),(0,1)).